# How to send parameters on clicking anchor tag in struts

Tags: java, struts2

I have anchor tag like below and I want to send input parameter username with it with out form submit.

```
<div class="">
    <form method="post" id="loginForm" action="<c:url value='/j_security_check'/>" onsubmit="saveUsername(this);
            return validateForm(this);" class="form-signin" autocomplete="off" style="left: 20px; position: absolute">
        <ul>
            <s:textfield id="j_username" name="j_username" placeholder="%{getText('label.username')}" requiredLabel="true" required="true" tabindex="1" cssClass="input-block-level i"/>
            <s:password id="j_password" name="j_password" placeholder="%{getText('label.password')}" requiredLabel="true" required="true" tabindex="2" cssClass="input-block-level i"/> 
            <li>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" name="login" tabindex="3">
                    <i class="icon-lock"></i> <fmt:message key='button.login'/>
                </button>
            </li>
            <li>
               <div style="margin-top:20px"> 
                  <a class="forgot_password" href="/forgotPassword">Forgot Password</a>    
               </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

On clicking anchor with `href=/forgot_password` which is inside form, I want to send `j_username` parameter to action class. How do I achieve this in struts because I am not using form submit here.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you add this JavaScript code and place `id="myanchor"` in your forgot password anchor tag. The `href` parameters value is ignored and placed through the Javascript. Place `onclick="sendUsername()"` on your anchor tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
function sendUsername() {
            var ctx = '${pageContext.request.contextPath}';
            var username = document.getElementById('j_username').value;
            document.getElementById('myanchor').href = ctx + "/forgotPassword?j_username=" + username+;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: but how can I send this to action class if I use javascript like this?

Comment: edit the url to map to your action class `document.getElementById('myanchor').href = ctx + "/j_security_check?j_username=" + username+;` maybe what you are looking for?

Comment: I guess, the action class is called automatically with `href` right? I am new to struts

Answer (score 1):

change below line

```
<a class="forgot_password" href="/forgotPassword">Forgot Password</a>
```

to

```
<a class="forgot_password" href="javascript:location.href='/forgotPassword?j_username='+document.getElementById('j_username').value;">Forgot Password</a>
```